# Center a <ul> list with a left float <li>'s with CSS

Tags: css

I have to reproduce a menu like this:

```
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
        Option 1  |  Option 2  |  Option 3  |  Option 4  |  Option 5
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

But actually I have this:

```
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
Option 1  |  Option 2  |  Option 3  |  Option 4  |  Option 5
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

My code:

```
<ul>
    <li>Option 1</li>
    <li>Option 2</li>
    <li>Option 3</li>
    <li>Option 4</li>
    <li>Option 5</li>
</ul>
```

My actual css for that code is:

```
ul { list-style: none outside none; margin:0; padding: 0; }
li { float: left; margin: 0 10px; }
```

How I can do it?

PD: IE7 alternative if possible.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Use this code for the `li`s instead:

```
li { margin: 0 10px; display: inline; }
```

And center your `ul`s' contents:

```
ul { list-style: none outside none; margin:0; padding: 0; text-align: center; }
```

Comment: this code works, but it fails in IE7. Any solution for IE7? Thank you!!

Comment: Try the updated code. Forgot IE7 doesn't support `inline-block`.

Comment: I also used `inline` for the `ul`

Answer (score 4):

Use `display: inline` in li and `text-align: center` in ul.

```
ul { list-style: none outside none; margin:0; padding: 0; text-align: center }
li { display: inline; margin: 0 10px; }
```

**Example: http://jsfiddle.net/ravan/gh29g/**

Comment: Breaks if you want to set the anchors inside the li's to `display: block;`

Comment: it's a menu right? or at least is has links, a tags, anchors? Do you set display: block on them? If so this shows the problem http://jsfiddle.net/ravan/gh29g/

Answer (score 1):

Just change the li's display to inline-block;
and add a `text-align:center` to the `ul`

See demo: http://jsfiddle.net/adardesign/6RZL4/

Comment: Not supported by older browsers (*cough* IE7 < *cough*)

Comment: There is also an artificial 'space' between elements, see https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/

Answer (score 1):

Making li items `display:inline` and list `text-align:center` will solve the problem in this case:

```
ul { list-style: none outside none; margin:0; padding: 0; border:1px solid #f33; text-align:center;}
li {display:inline; margin: 0 10px; border:1px solid #ccc; }
```

[image]

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mohsen/rzfPW/

But if your list items had more stuff in it(like menu items to show when mouse hover) then using `display:inline` is not good solution. because then the item is not an inline element.

You can do display:block and still have them aligned in center with float:left and having width and margin calculated by percent:

```
ul { list-style: none outside none; margin:0; padding: 0; border:1px solid #f33; text-align:center; padding:3px 0; overflow:hidden;}
li {display:block; width:16%; float:left; margin: 0 2%; background:yellow}
```

[image]

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mohsen/rzfPW/1/

Take note using percents and pixels(probably for borders) in your css will cause errors

Comment: Thanks, "overflow: hidden" is what I was looking for so the <ul> element doesn't collapse on the <li>

Answer (score -1):

Add padding: 0 10px; on the li

This some what centers the options - just play around with the padding until you are happy with it

Comment: Then resize the window and you have to fiddle again.