# Centre the links in a navigation bar

Tags: css, navigation, fluid

How do you centre the links themselves in the navigation bar?

The border is fluid and the nav buttons rearrange themselves to different screen sizes but I just can't get them to be in the middle, instead they are always on the left.

My HTML:

```
    <div id="centerment">

    <div id="navigation">
    <div id="menu4">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="index.html"> <span class="title"><strong>HOME</strong></span></a> </li>

    <li><a href="about.html"> <span class="title"><strong>ABOUT</strong></span></a></li>

    <li><a href="wood.html"> <span class="title"><strong>WOOD</strong></span> </a> </li>

    <li><a href="contact.html"> <span class="title"><strong>CONTACT</strong></span></a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

My CSS:

In all 3 responsive size: (mobile, tablet and desktop).

```
   #centerment {
position:relative;
clear: both;
float: left;
margin-left: 0px;
margin-right: 0px;
width: 100%;
display: block;

}



    #menu4 ul {
list-style: none;
font-family: "corbert regular regular";
font-size: 10px;
letter-spacing: 2px;
line-height: 1.2em;
float: left;
clear: left;
border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
border-top: 1px solid #000; 
    }


    #menu4 ul li{
float: left;
     }


     #menu4 ul li a{
display: inherit;
text-decoration: none;
color: #000000;
    text-align: center;
margin-left: 0 auto;
margin-right: 0 auto;
padding-top: 10px;
padding-right: 10px;
padding-bottom: 5px;
padding-left: 10px;
width: 170px
    }


    #menu4 ul li a span{
    display:inherit;
    }


    #menu4 ul li a span.title{

     }


    #menu4 ul li a:hover span.title{
color: #000000;
    }


    #menu4 ul li a span.text{
padding: 0px 5px;
font-family: "corbert regular regular";
font-size: 13px;
font-style: normal;
font-weight: 300;
letter-spacing: normal;
line-height: 1.6em;
color: #000000;
visibility: hidden;
    }


    #menu4 ul li a:hover span.text{
    visibility:visible;
     }


    .gridContainer.clearfix #navigation #menu4 ul li a .title {
font-family: Corbert;
     }
```

Many many thanks in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Center a <ul> list with a left float <li>'s with CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7506333/center-a-ul-list-with-a-left-float-lis-with-css)

Comment: Do you mean something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/SzHRw/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set containing element to text-align: center; then set the li's to display: inline-block; if there are no floats on the a tags this should do it.

Comment: Thanks very much. However I seem to have lost the relative position of the containing element. The words are centre but the nav bar is back to being on the left. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of borders on **#menu4 ul**, give it a margin of **-1px auto;**, add this:

```
#menuBox {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 53.2em;
  height: 30px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
  border-top: 1px solid #000; 
}
```

To contain the ul.

I originally posted the wrong link here is the correct one: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jYk5K/3/)

Comment: That did work but I lost the responsive nature of the nav bar especially on the mobile size.

Answer (score 0):

You can lose the ul and just use spans. Change your HTML to this:

```
<div id="centerment">
<div id="navigation">
<div id="menu4">
<div class="outer">
<span class="inner"><a href="index.html"><span class="title"><strong>HOME</strong></span>     </a></span>
<span class="inner"><a href="about.html"><span class="title"><strong>ABOUT</strong>    </span></a></span>
<span class="inner"><a href="wood.html"><span class="title"><strong>WOOD</strong></span> </a></span>
<span class="inner"><a href="contact.html"><span class="title"><strong>CONTACT</strong>     </span></a></span>
<span class="finish"></span>
</div></div></div></div>
```

Make sure to keep the "finish" span at the bottom of your list. That spaces all the links correctly.

Then add this to your CSS:

```
.outer {text-align: justify; width:70%; margin:0px auto; border-top:1px solid; border-bottom:1px solid;}

.outer span.finish {display: inline-block; width: 100%}

.outer span.inner {display: inline-block; white-space: nowrap}
```

Then change #menu4 ul to #menu4 .inner with this CSS:

```
#menu4 .inner {list-style: none; font-family: "corbert regular regular"; font-size: 10px; letter-spacing: 2px; line-height: 1.2em;
}
```

and change the "#menu4 ul li a" to say "#menu4 a"

That should do it. You can change the width % of .outer to play with the width of the nav as a whole.